# jQuery events, pass on params with context change

Tags: jquery

I have this basic code:

```
app.Modules.myModule = {
    init: function(){
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function(){
        app.Events.on('user:added', this.userAdded.call(this));
        this.username = $('#username');
    },

    userAdded: function(event, params){
        console.log(params);
        this.username.text(params.username);
    }
};
```

Now the problem I have, is that if I call this.userAdded as it is, then params doesn't get passed on to the userAdded function. If I don't use 'call' and just do this.userAdded, inside the userAdded function, then the context of 'this' is the jQuery event and not the 'app.Modules.myModule' like I need it to be.

So my question is, how can I keep the context of 'this' inside the userAdded function to the Object itself (myModule) and be able to pass it the params argument?

Comment: look at `$.proxy`  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you define your module as a function, the context can be set to a variable upon instantiation.  For example:

```
app.Modules.myModule = function(){

    var context = this;
    context.init = function(){
        context.bindEvents();
    };

    context.bindEvents = function(){
        app.Events.on('user:added', context.userAdded);
        context.username = $('#username');
    };

    context.userAdded = function(event, params){
        console.log(params);
        context.username.text(params.username);
    } ;       
};

var module = new app.Modules.myModule();
```

The context variable will now reference the context of the object, and can be used within the functions.  Make sure that you use the "new" keyword when initializing the object.

Comment: Then, the line in question would be....  context.userAdded()  and in "userAdded" just refer to "context" not to "this".